# Read xml document using jsp

Tags: xml, jsp

I need to read the xml document contents and read the key value pair using the xpath

document.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Disposition-Config>
    <LOB>
        <lob_pair key = "0" value = "N/A"/>
    </LOB>
    <SourceCode>
        <sourcecode_pair key = "0" value = "N/A"/>
    </SourceCode>
    <TerminationCode>
        <terminationcode_pair key = "0" value = "N/A"/>
    </TerminationCode>
</Disposition-Config>
```

jsp scriplet

```
<%
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

try {
    out.println(request.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/disposition.xml"));
    Document doc = db.parse(new File(request.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/document.xml")));
    out.println(doc);
    String  lobExpression = "/Disposition-Config/LOB/lob_pair";
    String  sourceCodeExpression = "/Disposition-Config/SourceCode/sourcecode_pair";
    String  terminationCodeExpression = "/Disposition-Config/TerminationCode/terminationcode_pair";
    CMETabReader cmeTabReader = new CMETabReader();
    /* class to retrieve key value from xml */
    cmeTabReader.getDispositionValues(doc, lobExpression);
} catch(Exception e) {
    out.print(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

%>
```

but when i try to print the xml doc using

```
<% out.println(doc) %>
```

its prints like

```
 [#document: null]
```

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("book.xml");
        XPathFactory xfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xfactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//lob_pair//@value");
        String result = (String)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);          
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And you can test your xpath expressions with this online parser http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Answer (score 0):

just change ur doc  pah like

Document doc = db.parse("http://l.h.:8087/rootfilename/xmlfilename.xml");

l means local and h=host;